# WCF client apps started to constantly receive timeout exceptions

Tags: c#, wcf

I am having a problem with WCF server side.
It started about a month ago, we didn't spot that before (approximately 1 year). Now our client apps started to constantly receive timeout exceptions.
Clients and service are desktop WPF applications. Service is hosted on a remote server.
Via debug (attached to host process) and logs (.svclog) we spotted that sometimes our host receives a lot of requests from the same ip address during a short period of time (and processing them takes multiple threads). 
9 of 10 requests failed with Communication Exception. Time between start and fail is different in every single case.  It varies from 20 minutes to 1 hour.
Meanwhile other clients can't connect to service. I have a suspicion that this happens because all available threads work with one client until it fails.
We modified ConcurrencyMode, UseSynchronizationContext manually, we didn't modify Send, Open, Receive, Close timeouts in host config, because as I understood they should default to 1 minute.
We want to break long requests or only allow one thread to process them.

Our service config:
.cs service file

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
```

app.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
       <wsHttpBinding>
         <binding name="htWsHttpEndpointBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="XService" behaviorConfiguration="htServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://ip/Xservice" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>   
        <endpoint address="http://ip/Xservice" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="htWsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="IXService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="htServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors> 
   </system.serviceModel>
```

Client app.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IXService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://ip/XService"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IXService"
                contract="IXService" name="WSHttpBinding_IXService"/>         
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Do you appropriately `Close()` / `Abort()` proxy client instances?

Comment: @Crowcoder  we use class from [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/622989/WCF-and-the-Try-Catch-Abort-Pattern)

Comment: Not so sure that is the best practice. See the first comment on that article. Also, `CommunicationState` is a race condition. It may not be the same state by the time you execute logic that branches based on state.

Answer (score 0):

```
ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single //set to multiple
```

You might have network issues, which result in retries and deadlock each other. In general your WCF Code should run async if hosted in a WPF application, otherwise you might be deadlocking youself on failing connections.

Comment: I've tried modify that parameter earlier, but it didn't solve the problem. And I revert it to Single, because it worked fine for a long time.
However I understood which issue it can make, so I'll set it to Multiple.

Comment: Still sounds like the usual deadlock with STA applications hosting a service. Start the Service in a seperate Thread and avoid synchronous calls from the service implementaion to the UI (e.g. Propery Changes, etc) -> can be tricky to drill down.